# Cannot import name 'Scatter' from 'bokeh.plotting'

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, scatter

I am trying to represent the data using the bokeh scatter.
Here is my code:

> ```
> from bokeh.plotting import Scatter, output_file, show import pandas
>
> df=pandas.Dataframe(colume["X","Y"])
>
> df["X"]=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
> df["Y"]=[23,43,32,12,34,54,33]
>
> p=Scatter(df,x="X",y="Y", title="Day Temperature measurement", xlabel="Tempetature", ylabel="Day")
> output_file("File.html")
> show(p)
> ```

The Output should look like this:
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdorZ.png)

The error is:

> 

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-14-1730ac6ad003> in <module>
> ----> 1 from bokeh.plotting import Scatter, output_file, show
>       2 import pandas
>       3 
>       4 df=pandas.Dataframe(colume["X","Y"])
>       5
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Scatter' from 'bokeh.plotting'
>   (C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\plotting__init__.py)

I had also found that the Scatter is no longer maintained now. Is there is any way to use it?
Also which alternative do I have to represent the data same as the Scatter using any another python libraries?

Using older version of Bokeh will resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scatter` (with a capital S) has never been part of `bokeh.plotting`. It used to be a part of the old `bokeh.charts` API that was removed several years ago. However, it is not needed at all to create basic scatter plots, since all the glyph methods in `bokeh.plotting` (e.g `circle`, `square`) are all implicitly scatter-type functions to begin with:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"X" :[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                   "Y": [23,43,32,12,34,54,33]})

p = figure(x_axis_label="Tempetature", y_axis_label="Day", 
           title="Day Temperature measurement")
p.circle("X", "Y", size=15, source=df)

show(p)
```

Which yields:

[image]

You can also just pass the data directly to `circle` as [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59671062/3406693).

If you want to do fancier things, like [map the marker type based on a column](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#markers) there is also a `plot.scatter` (lower case s) methods on the figure:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap, factor_mark

SPECIES = ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']
MARKERS = ['hex', 'circle_x', 'triangle']

p = figure(title = "Iris Morphology")
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Length'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Sepal Width'

p.scatter("petal_length", "sepal_width", source=flowers, legend_field="species", fill_alpha=0.4, size=12,
          marker=factor_mark('species', MARKERS, SPECIES),
          color=factor_cmap('species', 'Category10_3', SPECIES))

show(p)
```

which yields:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look up "scatter" in the docs, you'll find

> ## [Scatter Markers](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html?highlight=scatter#scatter-markers)
>
> To scatter circle markers on a plot, use the `circle()` method of Figure:
>
> ```
> from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
>
> # output to static HTML file
> output_file("line.html")
>
> p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
>
> # add a circle renderer with a size, color, and alpha
> p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
>
> # show the results
> show(p)
> ```

To work with dataframes, just pass in the columns like `df.X` and `df.Y` to the `x` and `y` args.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["X","Y"])

df["X"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
df["Y"] = [23,43,32,12,34,54,33]

p = figure()
p.scatter(df.X, df.Y, marker="circle")

#from bokeh.io import output_notebook
#output_notebook()

show(p)  # or output to a file...
```